# How to present parsed JSON in readable format to users?

Tags: android, arraylist, arrays, json

So I have JSON, I parsed in and it's sitting there. From my code below it looks like I have put everything into an ArrayList but then what? I mean for example I need the "title" of each JSON object to be an onClick on the first page, is that possible?

Essentially my onPostExceute() is empty/not doing much. Eventually I need to separate each object into it's own page via the onlicks I'm mentioning, but I think I can do that by separating the JSONObjects...? guess I'll come to that when I can.

If I want to separate things should I even be using an ArrayList? It's just what I used for a server test I ran with different code.

Would really appreciate some help. Basically stuck at the last hurdle is how I perceive it. Maybe I'm wrong though. The logs see that the JSON is showing up as one big chunk.

Edit: Removed my code, this is more of a theory question. ListView being the best thing to go with.

Comment: use a custom listview to display the items

Comment: @Raghunandan How would I go about that when I already have an ArrayList. In my XML should I just add a <ListView/> instead of TextView?

Comment: google for custom listview or search on stackoverflow you will find many related post with code snippets.

Comment: Fair enough I guess. I think I've found a youtube video on putting JSON data into a ListView using an ArrayList so if it works I'll post it here for others to see.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504615/how-to-display-parsed-xml-data-in-to-listview-in-android use this link it will help you

Comment: @MeenalSharma Do you know how that could be adapted for my doInBackground. I've never seen the XMLHandler thing before. Otherwise everything else makes sense.

Comment: after parsing you can save the data in list and in onpostexecute you can check the size of the list

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/android-full-app-part-6-customized-list.html this will give you the full tutorial

Comment: @MeenalSharma I managed to do it with this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TulTqQM0Cc I presume I would have to create two ListViews if I want only part of the data to show on the first listView then you click in and it tells you the rest.

Comment: yes you can do that...dats gud

Comment: @MeenalSharma Do you know how to get different parts of the JSON in the ArrayAdapter? So that it depends on what the user clicks? In my Example they can click on Google and only the id and link for Google will show, the same for Microsoft etc.

Comment: yes you can spearate arraylist for them..and can store them in diferent listviews...on google click you can open new listview showing id and link for google ..and so on..

Comment: @MeenalSharma I managed it by using the onItemClickListener(), so glad that works. If you put what you said into an answer I'll accept it for you. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can make spearate arraylist for them..and can store them in diferent listviews...on google click you can open new listview showing id and link for google ..and same you can do for microsoft and your other trem.And using onItemClick is a gud option,you can easily get the index of item clicked//